# psycopg2: how to dynamically create tables & insert values into postgresql db from excel file

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, psycopg2

I am looking to create a program that takes in an excel file with multiple sheets and dynamically creates Postgresql tables for each of the worksheets and also updates the db by inserting the respective values from the excel file.

I'm using `pyexcel_xls` to read the excel file and `psycopg2` to communicate with my DB. My biggest issue is being able to correctly form queries that `psycopg2` will accept, I've gone through this ->  http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html to dynamically create SQL queries but am still having errors.

Below you can see that I am reading the file, obtaining column names, and attempting to create a new table for each of these excel sheets, and also, insert the cell values from each column into their respective tables.

Using `psycopg` basic string manipulation using `%s`, doesn't work because the table/column names have to be dynamically retrieved from the file a user would provide.

```
dataset = pyxl.get_data(infile)
conn = connect("dbname=test user=user")
cur = conn.cursor()
tables = dataset.keys()

for table in tables:
    col_names = dataset[table][0]
    table_values = dataset[table]

    # Execute a command: this creates a new table
    snip = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in col_names)
    createsqltable = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {} (id serial PRIMARY KEY, {} VARCHAR(250))")
                    .format(sql.Identifier(table), snip)

    cur.execute(createsqltable)

    table_values.pop(0)
    # Insert cell values into created tables
    for row in table_values:
        vals = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in row)
        insert_sql = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})").format(sql.Identifier(table), vals).as_string(conn)
        print insert_sql
        cur.execute(insert_sql)
```

Currently the code outputs:
`raise TypeError("SQL identifier parts must be strings")
TypeError: SQL identifier parts must be strings` in the `CREATE TABLE` query because I believe the `snip` from above is a of type `sql.SQL`, what `psycopg2` calls a `Composable`.

I've been stuck on this problem for several days now and still haven't been able to find existing docs/issues that will build SQL query properly using the `psycopg2.sql` that `psycopg2` suggests. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the createsqltable line, shouldn't it just be snip as the argument to format instead of sql.Identifier(snip)?

Comment: Thanks for responding, changing it just to snip, instead of sql.Identifier(snip) helps with CREATE TABLE method, but INSERT is still throwing the same error, even if I use the same formatting.

Comment: Ah, right, the values should be sql.Literal not sql.Identifier.